# Get API with VueJS and axios : LifeCycle issue

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm doing a project and I need to use an API in a Vue project.
I'm trying to get some data from the API and it returns me nothing. (According to the console there is no issue nor warning message).
The title and the content print nothing and when I do my console logs only the third one is not empty.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div ref="myDraggable" class="draggable" id="cardpokemon">
    <div v-for="note in notes" v-bind:key="note.title">
      <h2>
        {{ note.title }}
      </h2>
    </div>
    <select onchange="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = this.value">
      <option value="">Pokemon Type</option>
      <option value="#F9F564">Electrique</option>
      <option value="#F58A51">Feu</option>
      <option value="#71E4FB">Eau</option>
      <option value="#FABEF0">Fée</option>
      <option value="#8EEC8D">Plante</option>
      <option value="#9789A9">Ténèbre</option>
      <option value="#B6B6B6">Roche</option>
    </select>
    <div class="subcard" v-bind:key="note.content" v-for="note in notes">
      <h3>
        {{ note.content }}
      </h3>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="buttonfleche" value="->" />
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import interact from "interactjs";
import axios from "axios";


export default {
  name: "Draggable",
  data() {
    return { 
notes: [{}]
    
,
      
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    axios.get('http://5.135.119.239:3090/notes/')
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(this.notes);
      this.notes = response.data; 
      console.log(this.notes);
    }.bind(this));
    console.log(this.notes)
    let myDraggable = this.$refs.myDraggable;
    this.initInteract(myDraggable);
   
    

  },
  
  methods: {
   

   
   
// <-------------------   START DRAG FUNCTION -----------------------> // 
    initInteract: function (selector) {
      interact(selector).draggable({
        inertia: true,

        restrict: {
          restriction: "parent",
          endOnly: true,
          elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 },
        },
      
        autoScroll: true,

     
        onmove: this.dragMoveListener,
       
        onend: this.onDragEnd,
      });
    },
    dragMoveListener: function (event) {
      var target = event.target,
        x =
          (parseFloat(target.getAttribute("data-x")) || this.screenX) +
          event.dx,
        y =
          (parseFloat(target.getAttribute("data-y")) || this.screenY) +
          event.dy;

      target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
        "translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";

      target.setAttribute("data-x", x);
      target.setAttribute("data-y", y);
    },
    onDragEnd: function (event) {
      var target = event.target;
      console.log(target);
      
      this.screenX = target.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      this.screenY = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    },
    // <---------- END DRAG FUNCTION -------------------------> // 



    // <------------ START SELECTOR COLOR CHANGE ---------------> // 

    onchange: function (param) {
      document.getElementById("tochange").style.background = param;
    },
  },
```

Comment: I dont think you need bind(this).

Comment: If I delete the bind(this), it returns me an error : "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'notes')"

Comment: Ok. What do you see in network tab? Do you see the request there?

Comment: In the console I can see that it returns me 3 proxys (because I did 3 console.logs). Only the third one returns me a non-empty proxy with the right amount of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your code. It is all about asynchronous code.

```
axios.get('http://5.135.119.239:3090/notes/')
.then(function(response){
  console.log(this.notes); // 2
  this.notes = response.data; 
  console.log(this.notes); // 3
}.bind(this));

console.log(this.notes) // 1
let myDraggable = this.$refs.myDraggable;
this.initInteract(myDraggable);
```

I've numbered the console.log() calls in order they are printed.

The first log prints nothing because it is called before the request resolves.

The second prints nothing because this.notes is not set yet.

The third prints the data after you have set it.

Also, you may want to lose `bind(this)` and replace the response callback with an arrow function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 
Now I understand the order. 
However I still don't get why my requests {{ note.title }} and {{ note.content }} don't work. They return nothing...

Comment: try using `this.$set(this, 'notes', response.data)` instead of direct assignment. it may be a reactivity issue.